# TT3 Attribute Block for sending an email using NFC

Tags: tags, format, uri, nfc, ndef

I want to send NDEF data through RC-S801 dynamic NFC tag with an Arduino which prompts the user to send an e-mail to a specified person with some subject and body. Can somebody tell which TT3 attribute block to use?
For URL I am sending

```
100101000300000000000000001b0030d102165370d1011255017374757474676172742e736f6e792e64650000000000
```

for "http://www.stuttgart.sony.de" which works fine but I am unable to construct TT3 attribute block for sending e-mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RC-S801, when used an NFC tag, operates according to the NFC Forum's Type 3 Tag Operation Specification. So I strongly suggest that you start by reading that specification (you can get it for free from the [NFC Forum's website](http://nfc-forum.org/)).

A type 3 tag's data area is divided in blocks of 16 bytes. The first block is the Attribute Information Block (i.e. the header of the data area). In your case that's

```
100101000300000000000000001b0030
```

The remaining blocks contain the NDEF data. In your case, that's

```
d102165370d101125501737475747467
6172742e736f6e792e64650000000000
```

**Attribute Information Block (AIB)**

- Byte 0 (`10`): Version information (1.0)
- Byte 1 (`01`): Number of blocks that can be read using one CHECK command. **Note that if you want to support Android 4.1.1 devices, you should change this to at least 2 (see [AOSP issue #36016](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36016)).**
- Byte 2 (`01`): Number of blocks that can be written using one UPDATE command.
- Bytes 3-4 (`0003`): Maximum available NDEF blocks (3 blocks).
- Bytes 5-8 (`00000000`): Must be set to zero.
- Byte 9 (`00`): Write flag, non-zero indicates an ongoing write.
- Byte 10 (`00`): Read/write flag, `00` indicates that the tag is read-only, `01` indicates that read/write is allowed.
- Bytes 11-13 (`00001b`): The actual size of the NDEF message in bytes (27 bytes). **You need to adapt this to the size of whatever NDEF message you want to have on your tag.**
- Bytes 14-15 (`0030`): Checksum over the AIB. **You need to adapt this if you change any value in the AIB.** The checksum is calculated as the sum of bytes 0 to 13 of the AIB. (The bytes are treated as unsigned integers.)

**NDEF Message**

Check the NFC Forum's NFC Data Exchange Format (NDEF) specification and the various record type definitions (RTDs) to learn how to format an NDEF message. In your case, the tag contains the following NDEF message:

```
+------------------------------------+
| SmartPoster Record                 |
+------------------------------------+
|                                    |
|  +------------------------------+  |
|  | URI Record                   |  |
|  +------------------------------+  |
|  | http://www.stuttgart.sony.de |  |
|  +------------------------------|  |
|                                    |
+------------------------------------+
```

If you want an e-mail link instead, you could use something like this:

```
D1 01 xx  55  06 <your e-mail address in UTF-8 encoding>
```

With xx being the length of `<your e-mail address in UTF-8 encoding>` plus 1. This will produce a link of the form `mailto:your@email.address`.

---

**Example**

```
10 02 01 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 39 00 50
D1 01 35 55 06 79 6F 75 72 40 65 6D 61 69 6C 2E
61 64 64 72 65 73 73 3F 73 75 62 6A 65 63 74 3D
54 65 73 74 26 62 6F 64 79 3D 54 68 69 73 20 69
73 20 61 20 74 65 73 74 2E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

This example contains a URI to send a predefined e-mail message with subject "Test" and body "This is a test." to the e-mail address your@email.address. The NDEF message consists of one URI NDEF record:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| URI Record                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| mailto:your@email.address?subject=Test&body=This is a test. |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

*NDEF record:*

- Payload length of the NDEF record: `35` = length(`06 79 6F ... 73 74 2E`)
- Type length of NDEF record: `01` = length(`55`)

*AIB:*

- Maximum number of available NDEF blocks: `0004` = length(`D1 01 34 ... 74 2E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`) / 16
- Size of NDEF message in bytes: `000039` = length(`D1 01 34 ... 73 74 2E`)
- Checksum: `0050` = `10` + `02` + `01` + `00` + `04` + `00` + `00` + `00` + `00` + `00` + `00` + `00` + `00` + `39`

Comment: The TT3 attribute block for prompting the user to send an email still is "100101000300000000000000001b0030" right ? This must be followed by D1 01 xx 55 06 <your e-mail address in UTF-8 encoding> I suppose.

Comment: Not really, you have to adapt the length of the NDEF message (currently `00001B`) and consequently the checksum (currently `0030`).

Comment: I am getting a bit confused here.Can you please post an example ndef message for prompting the user to send an email with a subject and a body which can be sent to the RC-S801 ?

Comment: @Micheal - I sent the ndef message that you have given as example above and I received something strange in the body of the email.Here is a pic of it - http://i.imgur.com/OVlaBPk.png[/IMG]

Comment: @Shreyas Right, see my update. It seems spaces in the URI should not be URL-encoded.

Comment: @Micheal - I sent your modified ndef data and now I am getting this :http://i.imgur.com/MINddw9.png[/IMG]

Comment: @Shreyas There was an off-by-one error in the length field of the NDEF record. This should be fixed now.

Comment: @Micheal Only a part of the message in the body is being detected.This is what is being detected : http://i.imgur.com/odZgODM.png[/IMG]

Comment: @Shreyas THen you are probably not properly sending the last block. Could it be that you did not properly adapt the example code you had to account for the extra block that I added to fit the whole message? Anyways, that discussion is already far beyond your initial question.